# Webrtc peer connection create answer/offer with different sdpConstraints

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, video, webrtc

Assume the following situation:

Peer A only wants to send audio stream to Peer B
Peer B only wants to send video stream to Peer A

Thus,

A create offer with

var sdpConstraints = {
            'mandatory': {
                'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
                'OfferToReceiveVideo': false
            }
};

When B received the offer and create the answer, what should the sdpConstraints be?

Is the assumption supported in webrtc? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking to do it seems like your constraints for A are backwards as A wants to receive Video and send audio.

You might want to try for A:

```
var sdpConstraints = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': false, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } };
```

and for B:

```
var sdpConstraints = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': false } };
```

Comment: It is just an assumption, any rule for it? If A sends Audio+video and B sends video only......

Comment: I tried with either true,the other one false, both didn't work. OfferToReceiveAudio and OfferToReceiveVideo have to be both true